# Python classes and modules

Tags: python

I am teaching myself Python and hit a roadblock with classes and modules.
The code below is something that you would probably never write, but I would like to just understand my error.

```
import random

class GetRandom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ""

    def ranNumber():
        return random.random()

b = GetRandom()
bnum = b.ranNumber
print bnum
```

The output I am getting is:

```
<bound method GetRandom.ranNumber of <__main__.GetRandom instance at 0x7fe87818df38>>
```

I had expected a random number between 0 and 1.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You forgot to actually invoke `GetRandom.ranNumber`.  Add `()` after it to do this:

   ```
   bnum = b.ranNumber()
   ```
2. You need to make `GetRandom.ranNumber` accept the [`self`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/2555451) argument that is passed implicitly when you invoke the method:

   ```
   def ranNumber(self):
       return random.random()
   ```

Once you address these issues, the code works as expected:

```
>>> import random
>>> class GetRandom:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.data = ""
...     def ranNumber(self):
...         return random.random()
...
>>> b = GetRandom()
>>> bnum = b.ranNumber()
>>> print bnum
0.819458844177
>>>
```